# How can I use use a regex to match characters that aren't included in certain words?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

Suppose I want to return all occurrences of 'lep' in a string in Python, but not if an occurrence is in a substring like 'filepath' or 'telephone'. Right now I am using a combination of negative lookahead/lookbehind:

```
(?<!te|fi)lep(?!hone|ath)
```

However, I do want 'telepath' and 'filephone' as well as 'filep' and 'telep'. I've seen similar questions but not one that addresses this type of combination of lookahead/behind.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure regex is the best tool for this?

Comment: Not positive, but I'm building the regex string from user provided search terms to search across a million or so code lines. I think I'd be better off running one regex pattern across each of those lines rather than each term in a list of terms across each of those lines.

Comment: Why is `telepath` allowed but not `filepath`?  How are you determining your criteria as to what words are allowed/disallowed?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What are you *really* trying to do?  Are you trying to find a list of certain words?  Are you just trying to exclude specific words from the match?

Comment: A user is entering terms to exclude and it would be sloppy to exclude terms the user didn't ask to be excluded. Therefore, if a user wants to exclude 'telephone,' I don't want to exclude some other arbitrary combination of excluded prefixes/suffixes. 'telepathy' is just an example, but 'telephone' does actually occur thousands of times in the result set without any sort of exclusionary criteria.

Comment: You can use something like `(?<!te|fi)lep(?!hone|ath)|telepath|filephone` (of course you can write a better version of it)

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. If I ask to exclude `tele`... I would expect `telephone` and `telepath` to be excluded... how does one decide what should or should not be excluded? Why are you selected a small subset to match instead of the entire exclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place lookaheads inside lookbehinds (and vice-versa; any combination, really, so long as every lookbehind has a fixed length).  That allows you to combine the two conditions into one (*doesn't begin with X **and** end with Y*):

```
lep(?<!telep(?=hone))(?<!filep(?=ath))
```

Putting the lookbehinds last is more efficient, too.  I would advise doing it that way even if there's no suffix (for example, `lep(?<!filep)` to exclude `filep`).

However, generating the regexes from user input like `lep -telephone -filepath` promises to be finicky and tedious.  If you can, it would be much easier to search for the unwanted terms first and eliminate them.  For example, search for:

```
(?:telephone|filepath|(lep))
```

If the search succeeds and `group(1)` is not `None`, it's a hit.

Comment: That's excellent. Thanks for your help. What makes putting lookbehinds last more efficient? Does it have anything to do with being able to disregard the lookbehind if the portion you are trying to match fails for a substring of the string being searched?

Comment: That's it exactly.  Lookbehinds aren't the performance-eating monsters many people make them out to be, but on very large texts like you're working with, the optimization is worthwhile.